# Login link with destination

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to create a login link in Drupal 7 that will

- keep the destination if set
- generate a destination based on the page on which the link was clicked if not set
- persist if set on subsequent clicks of the login link
- not be generated if not already set AND the currently viewed page is an undesirable destination (such as user/logout)

I have written the following code and put it into to the body of a block only shown to anonymous users, however, as I am new to Drupal's api can someone more knowledgable here check to see if this is OK or can be optimized, and/or what other destinations other than user/* should NOT generate a destination if the destination is not already set:

```
<a href="/user<?php $curpath = current_path();
if (strpos($curpath, 'user/') === 0 && !isset($_GET['destination'])) { 
  print '';
} 
else {
  $newdest = drupal_get_destination();
  $newdestimplode = implode('', $newdest);
  print '?destination=' . drupal_get_path_alias($newdestimplode);
} ?>">Login</a>
```

Alternatively if you know of a setting that puts the login link on pages for anonymous users with the above conditions or a LIGHTWEIGHT module (please don't suggest LoginTobboggan) that does this, let me know here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this THEME_menu_link override to add a destination parameter to login links:

e.g in `template.php`:

```
/**
 * THEME_menu_link override
 * Add unique class (mlid) to all menu items.
 * Add destination param to login link
 */
function THEMENAME_menu_link($variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  // Add destination to login link
  if ($element['#href'] == 'user/login') {
    $status = drupal_get_http_header('status');
    // don't add dest back to 403 etc..
    if(strpos($status, '403') !== FALSE){
      $dest = drupal_get_destination();
    }elseif(strpos($status, '404') !== FALSE){
      $dest = array('destination' => 'home');
    }elseif(strpos($_GET['q'], 'user/register') !== FALSE){
      $dest = array('destination' => 'home');
    }elseif(strpos($_GET['q'], 'user/login') !== FALSE){
      $dest = array('destination' => 'home');
    }elseif(strpos($_GET['q'], 'user/logout') !== FALSE){
      $dest = array('destination' => 'home');
    }else{
      $dest = array('destination' => drupal_get_path_alias());
    }
    $element['#localized_options']['query'] = $dest;
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'login';
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks pretty good. However, for some of your strpos conditions I would use === 0 as opposed to !=== FALSE because the former also ensures that the pattern occures at the beginning of the string, not anywhere in it.

Comment: Fair enough, === 0 will work fine also.