# Where do i change the settings of the redirected URL after a new user registers on my drupal 7 site?

Tags: 7, users, redirection

Where can i change the destination of the redirect after a user registers on my site? Currently it just hits them back to the homepage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can achieve it many ways

- Using Rules, create a RULE with **Event - After saving a new user account** and **Actions - redirect the page** and if you want you can also add **Conditions**, as per your requirement.

  [image]

  [image]
- Using **[hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)**

  `function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
      case 'user_register_form':
        $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_register_submit';
      break;
    }
  }
  function custom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'YOUR_REDIRECT_PATH_HERE';
  }`
- By using **destination parameter**

  - More simpler you can also using **destination parameter**. Just add
    the destination parameter in the URL where you want to **redirect
    it**. You can achieve it by using [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7). You can refer this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58506/login-link-with-destination#answer-58515)
  - `YOUR_DOMAIN/user/register?destination=YOUR_REDIRECT_PATH_HERE`

Note : Instead of writing the code or installing the module you can use  **Destination parameter** OR **RULES** .